# Insert new property to object using es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I would like to add new object inside the array of objects

```
const valueObj = Object.keys(values);
const filterCompetencies = competencies.filter(item =>
   item.competencies.find(i => !i.isComputational),
);

const filterComp = filterCompetencies.map(item => item.competencies);
const flatten = _.flattenDeep(filterComp);

const auditLogObj = flatten.map(item => ({
  employeeId: _.toNumber(currentUserId),
  actionName: `Updated target for ${item.name}`,
  actionDate: dateToday,
  actionBy: `${mentorSignature.firstName} ${mentorSignature.lastName}`,
}));

console.log(auditLogObj);
console.log(valueObj);
```

I want my object to insert new object it will look something like this

```
{
  employeeId: 243,
  id: "target-3-0",
  actionBy: "Sophia Vaughn",
  actionDate: "Nov 14 2020 14:49:29 PM",
  actionName: "Updated target for Mentorship (as mentee)"
},
{
  employeeId: 243,
  id: "target-3-1",
  actionBy: "Sophia Vaughn",
  actionDate: "Nov 14 2020 14:49:29 PM",
  actionName: "Updated target for Continuous Learning"
},
{
  employeeId: 243,
  id: "target-3-2",
  actionBy: "Sophia Vaughn",
  actionDate: "Nov 14 2020 14:49:29 PM",
  actionName: "Updated target for Certifications Passed"
},
...
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to augment your mapper so that for each new object it creates the corresponding id is taken from `valueObj` by index:

```
const auditLogObj = flatten.map((item, i) => ({
  id: values[i],
  employeeId: _.toNumber(currentUserId),
  actionName: `Updated target for ${item.name}`,
  actionDate: dateToday,
  actionBy: `${mentorSignature.firstName} ${mentorSignature.lastName}`,
}));
```